# Busca sem resultados no realtime database do Firebase

Tags: firebase, realtime-database

Olá, estou tentando acessar os itens contidos dentro de um usuário no realtime do firebase, mas o retorno do snapshot está vindo vazio, alguém sabe onde pode estar o error?

```js
const firebaseService = require('./firebaseService');
const {admin, customersDB} = require('./firebaseServices');
const getMd5 = require('./util').getMd5;


@param {string} email

const getUserProfile = (email) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      const profileRef = admin
        .database(customersDB)
        .ref(`profiles/${getMd5(email)}`);
        
      profileRef
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if(!snapshot.exists()){
            return reject(new Error('usuário não foi encontrado'));
          }
          return resolve(snapshot.val());
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    } catch(error){
      return reject(error);
    }
   });
```

O retorno tem sido sempre um 'Usuário não encontrado!'.

Answer (score 0):

há um erro no "chaining das promises"
eventualmente você nem precisa usar reject ou resolve a menos que queira personalizar o erro. eu prefiro simplesmente retornar o valor.

```
const getUserProfile = (email) => {
  try {
    const profileRef = admin.database(customersDB).ref(`profiles/${getMd5(email)}`);

    return profileRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      return !snapshot.exists() ? Promise.reject('usuário não foi encontrado') : snapshot.val();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
};
```